# How do you position an image such that it is partially off the screen without causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bu08sjar/1/

I have a page in which I want to absolute position an image (some fancy shape) such that it is partially off the screen but doing so causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear (especially when dragging around the viewport size in Chrome dev tools).

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <img class="some-svg" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/poi.svg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 90vh;
}

.some-svg {
  transform: scale(0.2);
  position: absolute;
  right: -450px;
}
```

I've tried `overflow-x: hidden` on the container but that does not appear to fix it. How do I structure my HTML/CSS in such a way that the images/shapes can sit partially off the screen while not causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear (essentially causing an increased width of the container)?

Comment: You have to apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to your body, not your container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `absolute` image is positioned relative to `<body>`, since your `.container` does not have `position: relative`.

Add that and `oveflow-x: hidden` will work.

*It will also work if `.container` has CSS `position: absolute` itself.*

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.some-svg {
  transform: scale(0.2);
  position: absolute;
  right: -450px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <img class="some-svg" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/poi.svg" />
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```